# What the pg_snapshots folder is used for

Tags: postgresql

At the pgdata root there is the pg_snapshots folder. Which PostgreSQL functionality is using that folder, what kind of data is written in there.

Answer (score 3):

`pg_snapshot` stores data for query snapshots that have been exported with [`pg_export_snapshot`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-SNAPSHOT-SYNCHRONIZATION).  The purpose of exported snapshots is that several database sessions can see exactly the same state of the database. This is for example used for parallel `pg_dump` with the "directory" format, but it can also be useful to synchronize the original data copy with the capture of data modifications via logical decoding.

Comment: I have added some more to the answer.

Comment: Ok, the pgdump example with parallelization is quite self-explanatory. Tks